# Safely restore disk labels and raid0 in Linux (CentOS 7) from external disk enclosure failure

Tags: raid, hard-drive, centos7, software-raid, mdadm

The SAS cable connecting my external disk enclosure to the server was broken so I replaced it with a new one.  However, after the re-connection all the disks came back with a different label, for example, sdi --> sdu, sdj --> sdv, etc. And the RAID0 array consisting of those disks also failed.

More details: the raid0 array was created from sd[ijklmnopqrst].  All the 12 disk labels have been changed after the re-connection. The error message I got from fdisk is `fdisk: cannot open /dev/md126: Input/output error`

Output of `cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md125 : active raid5 sdd[2] sdc[1] sdb[0]
      11718486016 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 2/44 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid0 sdj[0] sdi[9] sds[4] sdq[11] sdo[3] sdp[7] sdt[8] sdm[10] sdk[5] sdl[6] sdr[2] sdn[1]
      46882646016 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md127 : active raid0 sdh[3] sdg[2] sdf[1] sde[0]
      23436972032 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  5.5T  0 disk  
├─sda1               8:1    0  200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2               8:2    0  500M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3               8:3    0  416G  0 part  
  ├─centos-root    253:0    0  100G  0 lvm   /
  ├─centos-swap    253:1    0   16G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
  ├─centos-var     253:2    0   50G  0 lvm   /var
  └─centos-install 253:3    0  250G  0 lvm   
sdb                  8:16   0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md125              9:125  0 10.9T  0 raid5 /home
sdc                  8:32   0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md125              9:125  0 10.9T  0 raid5 /home
sdd                  8:48   0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md125              9:125  0 10.9T  0 raid5 /home
sde                  8:64   0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md127              9:127  0 21.8T  0 raid0 /temp
sdf                  8:80   0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md127              9:127  0 21.8T  0 raid0 /temp
sdg                  8:96   0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md127              9:127  0 21.8T  0 raid0 /temp
sdh                  8:112  0  5.5T  0 disk  
└─md127              9:127  0 21.8T  0 raid0 /temp
sdu                 65:64   0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdv                 65:80   0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdw                 65:96   0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdx                 65:112  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdy                 65:128  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdz                 65:144  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdaa                65:160  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdab                65:176  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdac                65:192  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdad                65:208  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdae                65:224  0  3.7T  0 disk  
sdaf                65:240  0  3.7T  0 disk
```

In `/etc/mdadm.conf` (CentOS changed md1 to md126 after rebooting):

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=a540f7c4-5839-4154-8399-42036a8664cf
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=759f63aa-b049-4e86-b4ce-c2391438807f
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=4ab4e822-9e63-41d0-a07b-daae3ea2bff7

ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=a540f7c4-5839-4154-8399-42036a8664cf
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=759f63aa-b049-4e86-b4ce-c2391438807f
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=4ab4e822-9e63-41d0-a07b-daae3ea2bff7
```

And the output of `mdadm -D /dev/md126` (the failed raid0):

```
/dev/md126:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Apr  5 19:54:19 2016
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 46882646016 (44710.78 GiB 48007.83 GB)
   Raid Devices : 12
  Total Devices : 12
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Apr  5 19:54:19 2016
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 12
Working Devices : 12
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      144        0      active sync
       1       8      208        1      active sync
       2      65       16        2      active sync
       3       8      224        3      active sync
       4      65       32        4      active sync
       5       8      160        5      active sync
       6       8      176        6      active sync
       7       8      240        7      active sync
       8      65       48        8      active sync
       9       8      128        9      active sync
      10       8      192       10      active sync
      11      65        0       11      active sync
```

It seems that the 12-disk raid0 array still exists. Below is the output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdu` (used to be in md126):

```
/dev/sdu:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : fef2dd89:7ef6045d:0b671362:244393f4
           Name : storage1.cluster.net:2
  Creation Time : Tue Apr  5 19:54:19 2016
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 12

 Avail Dev Size : 7813775024 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 82e28b37:5308ad64:ab0209d6:21b23484

    Update Time : Tue Apr  5 19:54:19 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 5d2d5658 - correct
         Events : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 9
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Error message from `dmesg | tail`:

```
[3525097.349398] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525127.415308] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525157.481331] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525187.547243] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525217.613119] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525247.679038] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525277.744885] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525307.810813] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525337.876736] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[3525367.942628] XFS (md126): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
```

Is there away to restore those disk labels as well as the RAID0 array without data loss?

Comment: What does your `mdadm.conf` look like?  If you are simply using the `ARRAY ... UUID=...` you may not need anything else.  Also, **RAID0 across 12 disk without data loss?**  RAID0 is the **I don't care about my data** version of RAID, if you wanted to avoid losing data, you should almost certainly be using something else.

Comment: @Zoredache The config file looks fine.  But I got IO error when trying to access.  Will rebooting solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't clear.  Edit your `mdadm.conf` into your question.  Also while you are at it, include the content of `lsblk`, and `cat /proc/mdstat`  You need to give us more information to work with.  I have no idea if rebooting will solve your problem, you haven't given us any information that would allow us to guess.

Comment: Looking at your `mdadm -D` and `mdadm --examine` output.  Is that information saved from your notes?  or was that current output?  It seems really unlikely it is current since the MAJ:MIN notes for the devices don't seem to match up with what lsblk is seeing. Also the `Update Time` in the output was from back in April?  At least on my active systems that value seems to be the last time that device was written to?  Also the `Array UUID` doesn't seem to match the values UUID you have in your `mdadm.conf`?

Comment: @Zoredache They are from the current output.  The UUID's from the mdam.conf are correct, but I don't know where the `Array UUID's` come from.

Comment: You might try stopping and assembling...  mdadm --stop /dev/md126 then mdadm --assemble --scan

Answer (score 0):

I simply reboot the system and solve the problem.